# Should we add a tag synonym for xdai to gnosis-chain

Tags: feature-request

With the token merger of xDai and Gnosis (see https://www.xdaichain.com/) it would make sense to make this visible on the Ethereum stackexchange too.

Therefore I would propose to add the `gnosis-chain` synonym for the `xdai` tag.

Note: I am missing the reputation on the `xdai` tag to propose the synonym ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems fair, the synonym should be working now.

Comment: Shouldn't `xdai` be a synonym of `gnosis-chain` though?

Comment: @q9f Since it was renamed from xdai to gnosis-chain it made sense to use gnosis-chain from now on, but I didn't realize that xdai post aren't shown at the old tag.